# Is auto uppercase for keywords in the SAP editor (6.0) possible?

Tags: ide, editor, abap

I am basically lazy to press <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> all the time, and I want the editor to recognize and automatically convert all my keywords to upper case.

Does SAP Editor v6.0 have this feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try going to SE38, Utilities -> Settings -> ABAP Editor -> Pretty Printer
And select "Keyword Uppercase".

Go back to the editor, click the `Pritty Printer` button or <kbd>Shift + F1</kbd>

[image: Pretty Printer settings screenshot]

Comment: I'm not sure which version was this feature implemented, please forgive me if it isn't available. GL.